# Callback functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, first-class-functions

I'm just getting started with Angular 2 and TypeScript and I can't seem to figure out how to use callback functions, I know this may be a silly question but given this regular javascript code:

```
someOnject.doSomething('dsadsaks', function(data){
      console.log(data);
});
```

What is the equivalent in TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same code works in TypeScript. Alternatively you can use

```
someOnject.doSomething('dsadsaks', data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The difference is that in the 2nd version `this.` would refer to the class surrounding the code.

Comment: hey you mean if `this` will refer to class variable or  function variable ??

Comment: @NaumanAhmad sorry, I don't understand what you mean. `this` refers to the class. I'm not dure myself what I referred to with this sentence ;

Comment: thanks i was just asking  if `this` when used in above callback function will it refer to class or call back function ?

Comment: To the class. .

Answer (score 4):

Your example is perfectly valid in a TypeScript project. If you wanted you could also strongly type your inputs:

```
const msg:string = 'dsadsaks'
someOnject.doSomething(msg, data:string =>{
      console.log(data);
});
```